# Extract feature importance from a mlflow 1.9 PyFuncModel model

Tags: python, xgboost, mlflow

**Top line**: How can I extract feature importance from an xgboost model that has been saved in mlflow as a PyFuncModel?

Details:

- I've picked up model update responsibilities from a data scientist who has just left. They used mlflow to tune hyperparameters. I need to understand the feature importance from the model they have built. My attempts of using `shap` have failed (my code below).
- I'm using mlflow 1.9.1. I can see that `mlflow.shap` exists in the current version, but this does not seem to appear in the version I'm on.

```
import mlflow
import shap

model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(model_load_details)  
print(f"model {type(model)})") 
# model <class 'mlflow.pyfunc.PyFuncModel'>)

explainer = shap.Explainer(model)
```

... which returns the error message "Exception: The passed model is not callable and cannot be analyzed directly with the given masker! Model: mlflow.pyfunc.loaded_model:"

**My own thinking**: Extract the parameter settings for the best model from mlflow, use these to retrain fresh xgboost model, then save as an xgboost flavor: From [here](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.xgboost.html), then use `mlflow.xgboost.save_model()`. But, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can get **feature importance** like that:

###### Setting mlflow configurations

```
mlflow.set_tracking_uri(MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI)  
mlflow.set_experiment(EXPERIMENT_NAME)
```

###### Reading model from mlflow

```
loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(f"models:/{MODEL_NAME_MLFLOW}/staging")
```

###### Getting Top 10 Features

```
data = {'feature_name':loaded_model._model_impl.python_model.model.feature_name_,    
'imp':loaded_model._model_impl.python_model.model.feature_importances_}


fi = pd.DataFrame(data).sort_values(by='imp', ascending=False)
top_10_features = fi.head(10)['feature_name'].to_list()
```